# Fsharp binding for monodevelop via add-in manager can't resolve dependencies

Tags: linux, git, f#, monodevelop, language-binding

I need to run F# with monodeveloper on Arch Linux. (Please don't advice me to NOT use it, i have to use it as it is required by a university course). I tried to add Language Binding for F# as it is described in this link(downloaded zip file, extract it and tried to add from add-in manager):

https://code.google.com/p/wildart/wiki/FSharpBinding

It gives me the following errors:

> The selected add-ins can not be installed because there are dependency conflicts.
>
> The package 'Components v2.2' could not be found in any repository
>
> The package 'Core v2.2' could not be found in any repository
>
> The package 'Core.Gui v2.2' could not be found in any repository
>
> The package 'Ide v2.2' could not be found in any repository
>
> The package 'Projects v2.2' could not be found in any repository
>
> The package 'Projects.Gui v2.2' could not be found in any repository

How can i solve this problem? I search on the internet and couldn't find a solution yet.

---

Second way, i tried to build and install from scratch as described in github:

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/tree/master/monodevelop

I've downloaded fsharpbinding.zip, installed nuget(i don't know what else i should download, as it says "required nuget packages"), unzip the file, and call ./configure.sh under his folder. It fails because it can't find fsc in given paths:

> which: no fsc in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

It successfully finds all other directories that it looks for. F# is already installed but i don't know how to find fsc to pass its path to configure.sh. What should i do?

Comment: The second error message is weird - fsharp has been fsharpc rather than fsc for quite a long time now.

Comment: @JohnPalmer, yeah i have commands fsharpc and fsharpi infact. I tried `./configure.sh -f fsharpc` but still gives the same error. In fact first link is quite old, second link must be current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just ran into this, and it seems to be [this issue](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/740). fixed it by uninstalling monodevelop and installing monodevelop-latest from aur

Comment: Perfect! It's installed now. Thanks a lot!